# Using Trig To Calculate dx,dy From Angle (bullet shot from gun)

Tags: python, trigonometry, angle

For a school project on CMU CS I am trying to use trig to calculate the speed/velocity for the dx and dy in order to make it move in the angle that the gun was pointing when shot. The code below is just related to the bullet and gun, thanks for your help! The grid goes from the top right(0) to bottom left (400.) (edit: forgot to mention game is top-down)

```
import math

player.gunAngle = angleTo(player.centerX,player.centerY,mouseX,mouseY) 
player.rotateAngle = player.gunAngle

-

bullet = Circle(gun.centerX,gun.centerY,4,rotateAngle = player.gunAngle)
bullet.angle = player.gunAngle
bullet.spawnX = gun.centerX
bullet.spawnY = gun.centerY

bullet.angle = math.radians(bullet.angle)

bullet.dx = 3 * math.cos(bullet.angle)
bullet.dy = 3 * math.sin(bullet.angle)

-

for i in bullets.children:
i.centerX += rounded(i.dx)
i.centerY -= rounded(i.dy)
```

When I shoot it, I think I did something wrong with the calculations but it goes it the wrong direction, even if I shoot multiple times in the same spot they all shoot in the same wrong direction, and im not sure what is wrong with the calculations so I don't know how to fix it. The grid goes from the top right(0) to bottom left (400.)

Comment: Why did you convert the angle to degrees?  The trigonometric functions in `math` exclusively work with radians, *not* degrees.

Comment: @jasonharper I wasn't sure which one to use, but when I did use radians, it still shot incorrectly, but the only time it shot out correctly was when the gun was facing the top-right or bottom-left

Comment: What exactly does `angleTo()` return?  If it's already in radians, then applying `math.radians()` to it is inappropriate.

Comment: @jasonharper 'Returns an integer representing the angle from the point (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) with straight up being 0 degrees.'

Comment: Do you want the angle for something else? you've got one dx/dy pair that you are passing to `angleAt` then converting that angle back to a dx/dy pair, if you don't need the angle they you just need to normalize the first one and multiply by the bullet speed.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Do you mean the different mouse cords in angleTo(player.centerX,player.centerY,mouseX,mouseY)? How would I go about normalizing that so I could move the bullet at a constant speed in that direction?

Comment: Don't work with angles, work with the velocity vector (or if you need frame-independence, the trajectory formula for a bullet is one of the oldest things we used computers for, so the formulae are pretty well documented and easily found on the web. As long as you know your bullet's weight, and the initial angle and velocity, we can know its entire path before your code even starts animating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the angle for something else, you can just use the vector components and convert the difference between player and mouse positions into a unit vector, then scale than vector's components by however fast you want the bullet to move:

To get a unit vector you divide the components by the euclidean magnitude:

```
gun_dx = mouseX-player.centerX
gun_dy = mouseY-player.centerY
gun_mag = math.sqrt(gun_dx*gun_dx + gun_dy*gun_dy)
bullet.dx = bullet_speed * gun_dx / gun_mag
bullet.dy = bullet_speed * gun_dy / gun_mag
```

You will need to add a check for division by zero magnitude, either here or before firing the gun on mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

### Good performance habits.

- Reduce number of divisions whenever possible.
- Prefer branchless code whenever possible. ie avoid conditional statements.

### Appling good habits

A slight improvement on the given answer removes some multiplication and divisions. The two divisions become multiplications with the division being done once by calculating the inverse distance to mouse normalized to the bullet speed.

To avoid a divide by zero or a conditional branch, add a tiny fraction (of smallest visible unit eg pixel size) to the mag. It's so small it has no visible effect on the bullet speed.

```
gun_dx = mouseX-player.centerX
gun_dy = mouseY-player.centerY
gun_delta_scale = bullet_speed / (math.sqrt(gun_dx * gun_dx + gun_dy * gun_dy) + 0.0001)
bullet.dx = gun_dx * gun_delta_scale
bullet.dy = gun_dy * gun_delta_scale
```

Totally insignificant if only done once per frame. But it can quickly become worthwhile if you have many things needing normalized vectors to coordinates.